# Laravel - Set up dynamic database connection on Multi tenant application

Tags: database, laravel, dynamic, multi-tenant, laravel-5.4

Within my app I have different businesses and those have a number of users.
For example:

- Business A has UserA, UserB and UserC
- Business B has UserD and UserE

And so on..

Each business has its own separate database, so Users A, B and C access the same database, and Users D and E access a different database (Every tenant database is identical in structure, the only thing that differs is the data).

There is a main database that has this information for each user, so I know which database a user belongs.

```
'main' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => 'hostname',
    'database' => 'main_database',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'prefix'   => '',
),

'tenant' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'database' => DYNAMIC_DATABASE_NAME_GOES_HERE,
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'prefix'   => '',
),
```

I need to find a way to do the following in Laravel:

1. User signs in to the app
2. After login I get the user database identifier/database name using the main database connection
3. Set that specific database name within a connection called "tenant"
4. App uses that tenant connection to load the data of that specific
   user/business

How can I accomplish this in Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/set-up-dynamic-database-connection-globally) has a very good example of what you are looking for.

1) Setup two connections in your database config.

```
'main' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => 'hostname',
    'database' => 'database',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'prefix'   => '',
),

'tenant' => array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'host'     => '',
    'database' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'prefix'   => '',
)
```

2) Then to switch the DB, put the following code in your filters or middleware. Considering you have `Tenant` model for database connection info.

```
$tenant = Tenant::whereSubDomain($subdomain)->first();  

Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', $tenant ->host);
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', $tenant ->username);
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', $tenant ->password);
Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $tenant ->database);

//If you want to use query builder without having to specify the connection
Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');
\DB::purge('tenant');
\DB::reconnect('tenant');

dd(\DB::connection('tenant'));
```

3) Specify following in your models

```
//On models dealing with the main DB
protected $connection = 'main';

//On models dealing with tenant DBs
protected $connection = 'tenant';
```